# Creating instances of a class with names from a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

There is a list of lists

```
[[name1, value1], [name2, value2], ...]
```

I need to create instances of a class with names name1, name2, and so forth, i.e., with names taken from the `list[1][1]`,  `list[2][1]`, etc.
But I can't imagine ways in which this can be implemented.

Class:

```
class func():
    def __init__(self, visibility, ftype, body):
    ...
```

List:

```
list = [
    ['private', 'Void', 'SetupWheels', 'body'],
    ...
]
```

Dictionary:

```
func_list = {}
```

It should look like this:

```
for i, val in enumerate(c):
    *new key in the dictionary is equal to the value val[2]* = func(val[0], val[1], val[3])
```

Comment: I suggest that you seriously reconsider what you're trying to do: See [**_Why you don't want to dynamically create variables_**](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populate a dictionary with instances of a class whose attributes were taken from a list of lists, you can use a [`dict` comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) like:

#### Code:

```
func_list = {row[2]: Func(row[0], row[1], row[3]) for row in c}
```

#### Test Code:

```
class Func():
    def __init__(self, visibility, ftype, body):
        self.visibility = visibility
        self.ftype = ftype
        self.body = body

    def __repr__(self):
        return "v:%s f:%s b:%s" % (self.visibility, self.ftype, self.body)

c = [
    ['private', 'Void', 'SetupWheels', 'body'],
    ['private', 'Void', 'SetupWheelx', 'bo8y'],
]

func_list = {row[2]: Func(row[0], row[1], row[3]) for row in c}

print(func_list)
```

#### Results:

```
{'SetupWheelx': v: private f:Void b:body, 'SetupWheels': v: private f:Void b:body}
```